# Rate module stops working and admin menu disappears on frontpage - fixed by flushing cache

Tags: 7, caching, rating

At random times, the Rate widget in a view on my frontpage stops working, and the votes are no longer recorded. The users are also able to click the vote widget on their own content when this happens, even though it's not allowed. That vote is not recorded either, but the widget turns into a link, and it shouldn't. The admin menu also disappears.

And all this only happens on the front page. It's easily fixed by flushing the cache, but that's not very efficient :)

How can I fix this issue from happening again?

Comment: Soooo...what's the actual question?  What causes it?

Comment: @Chapabu Sorry, forgot that part. Edited the question.